# How to find a column with null and not null values in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table where I need to find a column with null and not null values. for e.g. The column has a value today but becomes null tomorrow.

First Query:

```
select * from test where Account Number is Not Null and LastChangedDate is Null
```

But this query brings the records with null values and not listing the records with values for LastChangedDate column

Below is the sample record

```
AccountNumber EffectiveDate LastChangedDate 
1234567     2019-05-31          2018-09-14
1234567     2019-06-30          2018-09-14
1234567     2019-07-31           NULL
```

Second query:

```
select * from test where Account Number is Not Null and 'LastChangedDate' is Null
```

But this query brings the records with null values and not listing the records with values for 'LastChangedDate' column

Expected: Able to retrieve all records for same column with Null and Not Null values and omit the records with all values populated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEAD()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.*, 
        LEAD(LastChangedDate) OVER(PARTITION BY AccountNumber ORDER BY EffectiveDate) LastChangedDateLead
    FROM test t
) x
WHERE LastChangedDate IS NULL OR LastChangedDateLead IS NULL
```

This will give you the records where `LastChangedDate` is `NULL` or for which the next record (for the same customer and ordered by `EffectiveDate`) has a `NULL` value as `LastChangedDate`.

NB: the latest record of each customer will show up in the result: since there is no next record, the query will consider that its `LastChangedDate` is `NULL` too.

This **[demo on DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=114c94619c9c1111f9aa9725a15b18b6)** with your sample data returns:

```
AccountNumber | EffectiveDate       | LastChangedDate     | LastChangedDateLead
------------: | :------------------ | :------------------ | :------------------
      1234567 | 30/06/2019 00:00:00 | 14/09/2018 00:00:00 | null               
      1234567 | 31/07/2019 00:00:00 | null                | null
```

Comment: Thanks GMB but I'm getting records only with null values, actually I need to get same account number with LastChangedDate value populated and in case of null then display the null record as well, above query retrieves only the Null records

Comment: In this case I don't know the account number out of millions of records

Comment: @Raj: *I'm getting records only with null values* : no you don't, you get records that have an empty `LastChangedDate` or whose next record has an empty `LastChangedDate `. I added a DB Fiddle tom my answer for your reference.

Comment: Apologize, yes I do see the dates followed by null values, initially there were many records only with null. Thanks a lot for your help GMB, please have this closed.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it together:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE (Account Number is Not Null and 'LastChangedDate' is Null)
```

Comment: Thank you GMB, your query works fine, kindly close this question.

Comment: I accepted the answer, thanks a lot for all your help.